# how to access table from rails console if the table has _ in its name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access all records of a table that has an underscore in its name. 
For example if I have table in my schema that is called `trips` I can do `Trip.all` in rails console. But what do I do if my table name contains an underscore (e.g. `users_foods`)

I tried the following options:

```
Users_food.all
User_food.all
User_foods.all 
etc.
```

All of the above did not work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out 
One can access the data with `UserFood`

Answer (score 0):

For a table named `users_foods`, ActiveModel should provide you with a corresponding Rails model `UsersFood`, to fit Ruby/Rails object naming convention. Try that.

Class names `Users_food` or `User_food`, etc. do not conform to Ruby convention.

Comment: does not work. I think I will just change my schema name to conform with the ruby convention

Comment: Interesting (and odd). No, your table names are fine, and should actually NOT be changed to Ruby convention. That's the whole point of ActiveModel (a part of Rails), which abstracts away db-specific operation from Ruby objects and models.

Comment: So do you have a different suggestion ?

Comment: It must be something far more fundamental. Perhaps with the setup of Rails itself. Or the corresponding model. To confirm this, I would launch a brand new default Rails app (via $ rails new new_app), and then create a new model via $ rails generate model UsersFood username:string. Then running $ rake db:migrate should create a db table called users_food. Basically this verifies the reverse of what you have been trying to do. If that works, you can use its setup as a comparison to the project that isn't working for you.

Comment: figure it out it is UserFood

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating `bonus_histories` table. And didn't work any of the answers until I found out why.

I have made only `rails g migration BonusHistory` 
and it was the problem. My rails console didn't find BonusHistory at all because I had no model.

So I had to first rollback the migration `rake db:rollback STEP=1`, then deleted the migration file and finally made 
`rails g model BonusHistory` 
and after migrating that table, when I enter rails console, I can successfully ask for `BonusHistory.count`